# Is there any way of making post tags (or custom post type tags) pop up as suggestion as in StackExchange sites?

Tags: tags

In any SE site, there are suggestions that pop out when you are writing in the **Tag** field. Is there any way of doing something similar in Wordpress? (a simple vertical list is enough).

(Maybe helped with jQuery).

Comment: jQuery autocomplete

Comment: @kaiser Is jQuery able to get Wordpress tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should do this by default if there are tags to suggest, but I think there's a little bit of a delay before the suggestions show. You can also choose from your most used tags, which some might find easier to use.

Comment: are you sure it is by default? because I've never seen that feature.

Comment: Yep, I use it quite often and just tested it out.

Comment: Do I have to activate it? Because I typed some letters and waited for 2 minutes and nothing popped up.

Comment: No, shouldn't have to activate anything, but of course it will only match tags you have previously used. Do you have any JS errors or a plugin/theme installed that could be interfering with it? Here's a screenshot of it working for me: http://cl.ly/3E323P2G40413t3L1m39

Comment: Oh now, I understand. No, my idea was to make tags that are stored in the database pop up. Not the ones I've already used myself.

Comment: Hmm, is this an external DB or something else I'm not considering? There are no tags in the WordPress DB except ones that you've used or added. If it's in the DB, even if it hasn't been used for any posts, it'll appear in the autosuggest (which I also just tested to be sure!).